# Why is Redis not accepting slaveof command?

Tags: redis, replication

I have a pair of Redis on my machine. They are set as master/slave. Redis1 master. Redis2 slave.

Whenever I stop the Redis1 (master) the Redis2 assumes as master.

Then I start the Redis1 again. It start as slave (as it was supposed).

If I type in the Redis1:

```
slaveof no one
```

It assumes as master. But 5 seconds after Redis2 assumes as master again.

Any hint on this behavior?

[Redis slaveof doc](https://redis.io/commands/slaveof).

---SOLUTION--

there was a sentinel active changing the setting. Thank you @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: Do you have sentinel set up between them?

Comment: No sentinel @Not_a_Golfer

Comment: then how come redis1 returns as a slave if it doesn't have a master?

Comment: It has the relation configured on their setting

Comment: you state that you start with redis1 as master and redis2 as slave. when you stop redis1, redis2 becomes a master becasue it has no master. so far so good. But there is no reason for redis1 to become a slave of redis2 when you start it unless you change its settings. So I'm missing something.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, my docker had a sentinel configured as well. So you are right

Comment: Sentinel change the setting of the server so it will always be turned into slave

Comment: So probably sentinel reconfigures redis1 to be the slave again.

Comment: well, mystery solved! :)

Comment: Information updated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the investigation as an answer for future generations:

The set-up on docker also included a sentinel, that performed a fail over and made redis1 a slave of redis2 when it returned to the game.

Comment: Dude - you rock!

Comment: @ItamarHaber no, you're schmoopy <3